# How to disable a Firebase service

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I recently started using firebase and I selected all of the options when using <kbd>firebase init</kbd>

And now I can't deploy. I searched the docs and did not find an answer.

Comment: Answer below. But if you're having a concrete problem, it's more likely someone can help if you describe the [minimum steps that anyone can take to reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the services is just a node in the `firebase.json` file that is generated for you. So you can disabled the service by removing that node from the file.